# Is there open source elearning software that works easily on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

I run Ubuntu 11.04 and am an elearning specialist.  Many people use adobe elearning packages (articulate, storyline and captivate) to develop online learning programs.

Is there an open source equivalent?

Do these programs run on Ubuntu?

I'm looking forward to a reply, I have searched many places for alternative and have so far not been able to find anything.

I don't write code or work in the 'backend' so it has to be easy to install and manage.

Comment: What are the features you'd need in an e-learning software? Because there are several packages that can record screens and there are plenty of video editors available. Also, Windows softwares can be made to run on Ubuntu (or any GNU/Linux distro) using a package called Wine. In the end, it depends on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

The best I ran in to would be ...

> [Wink](http://www.debugmode.com/wink/)

Wink is a Tutorial and Presentation creation software, primarily aimed at creating tutorials on how to use software (like a tutor for MS-Word/Excel etc). Using Wink you can capture screenshots, add explanations boxes, buttons, titles etc and generate a highly effective tutorial for your users.

Features:

1. Freeware: Distributed as freeware for business or personal use. However if you want to redistribute Wink, you need to get permission from the author.
2. Cross-Platform: Available for all flavours of Windows and various versions of Linux (x86 only).
3. Audio: Record voice as you create the tutorial for explaining better.
4. Input formats: Capture screenshots from your PC, or use images in BMP/JPG/PNG/TIFF/GIF formats.
5. Output formats: Macromedia Flash, Standalone EXE, PDF, PostScript, HTML or any of the above image formats. Use Flash/html for the web, EXE for distributing to PC users and PDF for printable manuals.
6. Multilingual support: Works in English, French, German, Italian, Danish, Spanish, Serbian, Japanese, Brazilian Portuguese and Simplified/Traditional Chinese.
7. Smart Capture Tools: Capture screenshots automatically as you use your PC, based on mouse and keyboard input (great time saver and generates professional captures).
8. Performance/Quality: Creates highly compressed Flash presentations (few kbs to few hundreds of kbs, much smaller than competing commercial products) ideal for using on the web.

There are 2 others but they seem to lack features Wink does have: [Kazam](https://launchpad.net/kazam) and [Tibesti](https://launchpad.net/tibesti).

It is not in the repositories though so you need to [install it from source](http://www.debugmode.com/wink/download.htm). I only found a [how-to on installing on x64](http://www.bitsbythepound.com/installing-wink-on-64-bit-ubuntu-210.html) but looks like it is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

Check out eXeLearning: it was originally developed by the Ministry of Education of New Zealand and it is now being worked on by my company and the open source center of the Spanish government.

> [eXeLearning](http://www.exelearning.net)

It has a lot of the features from Captivate ; you can add video/audio, export to SCORM, make quizzes, use mini games etc.  eXeLearning 2.0 beta has more features and is being stabilized now.

Answer (score 1):

[Adapt Learning](https://www.adaptlearning.org/) is a tool for creating e-learning that will run just fine on Linux. Not only that, it's open source too ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [JoomlaLMS](http://joomlalms.com), it is a component for Joomla and they are installed together on any windows or linux server meeting these requirements: http://www.joomla.org/technical-requirements.html. 
Although JoomlaLMS is not a 100% open source software (it's a commercial product), but the professional version can be fully customized. It's quite rich in features and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised joomla, drupal, and Moodle are not mentioned. All major truly open source and moodle is the leading learning management system (LMS)